# AWS load balancer health check with api key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, health-check

When doing health check in AWS application load balancer, I need set health check to path `/service_name/health`

But it also need be accessed with `api key` (a header)

How can I implement this type of health check?

Answer (score 3):

Health checks do not support passing custom headers. You are limited to the following:

- Path
- Port
- Protocol
- Status code(s)

As an alternative to your solution could you use a query string with the API key instead of the header?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is **no direct way of doing this**, without a proxy. ALB only supports `GET` for heath checks.

A workaround is to **set status code to 403** (or whatever is returned from your service on failed authentication) instead of 200. This usually works since if the service responds with expected failed authentication code (e.g. 403) you can assume that the application is working.

Comment: Is this still valid? Docs mention matcher expected in the 200-399 range